# libSkiaSharp.dll can not be loaded in Azure Function Environment

Tags: azure-functions, skiasharp, aspose.words

I'm using the Aspose.Word and attach HTML to the document. When there is a link to a GIF in the HTML it crashes with this error message:

`The version of the native libSkiaSharp library is incompatible with this version of SkiaSharp. Supported versions of the native libSkiaSharp library are in the range [88.1, 89.0).`

The project is .Net 6.0 and in Visual Studio during Debug it works.

The Azure Function runs on a Windows Environment. I tested 32bit and 64bit. The libSkiaSharp.dll is deployed to

bin/runtimes/win-arm64/native
bin/runtimes/win-x64/native
bin/runtimes/win-x86/native
bin/runtimes/win7-x64/native
bin/runtimes/win7-x86/native

in the same version as it locally run.

I intalled SkiaSharp by Nuget directly. I also updated Aspose.Word to the newest version.

I don't think, that the version is wrong. I assume the there may be a problem with the CPU-Architecture on the server.

Some ideas, what it can be?

Comment: The problem might be related to this https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/1001

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after hours I found out, that the problem is related to the deployment.

The deployment was made with a release pipeline with an App Service Deployment.

After I deployed it with VS it worked. On the other stages I deployed with Azure Function Deployment instead of Azure App Service Deployment and it works there, too.

There was also a warning not to use Azure App Service Deployment for Azure Function.

I also checked after that for differences. The main difference was, that this it now runs from package. If this is the reason for not loading native components, I don't know.